Angular / Typescript - Use a base class for common functions
We are in the process of re-writing our components to be stand-alone and re-useable.  Please note we are using Angular 16, and can not upgrade to a newer version yet.
I'm trying to create a base class to handle error messages, loading, and other common functionality.  In this base class, I have a behavior subject that is not being updated, other than in the ngOnInit.  What I'm trying to do is to pass a boolean to show that the service call was successful, and show a false in the base.component.html:6
I've tried various things, with no success.  Maybe I'm missing something obvious with how base classes work in typescript versus what I'm used to in C#.
Thanks in advance, here's the stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-r6ncxp?file=README.md
app.component.html
<div class="content" role="main">
  This is from the app.component.html
  <app-home></app-home>
</div>

base.component.ts
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { Component, Input, OnInit, TemplateRef } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base',
  templateUrl: './base.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./base.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() templateRef: TemplateRef<any> | null = null;     // reference to the child template to be projected
    isLoading$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
      // if I call this from the home component, then isLoading$ updates
    }

    handleEvent(foo: any) {
      console.log(`from handleTestLoadingEvent: ${foo}.`);
      this.isLoading$.next(foo);

    }

    inheritEvent(foo: boolean) {
      console.log(`base component inheritEvent value: ${foo}`);
      this.isLoading$.next(foo);
    }
}

base.component.html
<div>
  <p>
    This is the base.component.html
  </p>
  <p>
    isLoading$: {{ isLoading$ | async }}
  </p>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet='templateRef' (isLoading)="handleEvent($event)"></ng-container>
</div>

home.component.ts
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseComponent } from '../base.component';
import { FooService } from '../service/foo.service';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [BaseComponent, CommonModule],
  providers: [FooService]
})
export class HomeComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() isLoading: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(private fooService: FooService) {
    super();
   }

  override ngOnInit(): void {
    // Emit this to the base component
    this.fooService.getFoo(1234).subscribe(f => {
      console.log(`foo Service has been called successfully: ${f}`);
      this.isLoading.emit(f);
      this.inheritEvent(f);
    });
  }
}

home.component.ts
<app-base [templateRef]='homeTemplate'>
  <ng-template #homeTemplate>
    This is from home.component.html
  </ng-template>
</app-base>


Please include all relevant code as plaintext in the question itself. Links to code are not sufficient to be a [mre]. Until the code is included here as plaintext, the question risks being closed as needing debugging details.

Edit:  Added relevant code samples

Could you please provide a link where states that binding to Output of a projected component is supported?

I don't think it is supported, I was just trying different things to get it to work.  I'm unclear on how angular base components work for my scenario.

@dave2118 okay, I thought I missed something :) So far I know, your problem is not solvable in the way you are trying to implement it. But frankly I don't understand why you can't trigger handleEvent directly from HomeComponent? This intermediate step (isLoading)="handleEvent($event)" just hides method usages and doesn't really bring you anything. Also, it is very possible that the whole idea with inheritance is wrong (many things in Angular can be achieved by composition, not inheritance) but I need more details to be sure

i Would recommend you to change your design, but in the meanwhile lets work with this.
There are some changes you need to make to fix this:
1.- The ng-container does not support Output so the BaseComponent nevers get called with the (isLoading).
2.- The BaseComponent is created twice, one from the extends from HomeComponent an another from the declaration tag  so you are dealing with two instances.
3.- There is a cyclic dependency between HomeComponent and BaseComponent.
Now lets fix those issued to make it work.
In the HomeComponent use the @ViewChild to access the instance of the base-component, and delete the extends, then replace the access to BaseComponent with the instance.
  @ViewChild(BaseComponent, { read: BaseComponent, static: true })
  base!: BaseComponent;

Create a new class (An standalone directive) i called CommonComponent (rename it to whatever you want) and make HomeComponent to extends it, with this will be able to inject any component in the BaseComponent.
@Directive({ standalone: true })
export class CommonComponent {
  @Output() isLoading: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
}

In the HomeComponent providers, provide the new class with the existing HomeComponent.
  providers: [
    FooService,
    { provide: CommonComponent, useExisting: HomeComponent },
  ],

And last, inject into the BaseComponent the CommonComponent (remember this can be any component that was provided) and subscribe to the events of it.
  constructor(private component: CommonComponent) {
    console.log('BaseComponent!');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.component.isLoading.asObservable().subscribe((e) => {
      this.handleEvent(e);
    });
  }

Now you are able to communicate between the decoupled components.
This is the example of your project https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hxyvl4 in case i missed something.

Thank You so much!  I apparently still have a lot to learn about angular.
